# Solution of partial difference equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, finite-differences

I want to find the explicit solution of the following difference equation

$e_{i,j+1}=re_{i-1,j}+(1-2r)e_{i,j}+re_{i+1,j}+km_{i,j}$

where $r>0$, $k>0$ and $m_{i,j}$ are known and $e_{i,0}=0$. My approach is that as in the solution of PDE by seperation of variables, i.e,

$e_{i,j}=X_{i}T_{j}$

but I couldn't go further. Is there any other approach to solve this?

Comment: $i$ starts from $1$ to $n$ or $i$ can take all integers?

Comment: $i$ starts from $1$ to $n$ and $e_{0,j}=e_{n,j}=0$ for all $j$